# Why doesn't sbrk() tell me how much of the heap I'm using?

Tags: c, memory

I have a game engine for which I wanted to quickly see how much of the heap it was using so I implemented these two small routines

```
static void * start_memory = 0;
unsigned long System::memoryUsage(){
    void * here = sbrk(0);
    return (char*) here - (char*) start_memory;
}

void System::startMemoryUsage(){
    start_memory = sbrk(0);
}
```

I call startMemoryUsage() very early in my main(). When I use this at runtime I usually see relatively low values, like 300kb, but top says the RSS is somewhere around 30mb. How come I'm not getting an accurate measurement from sbrk()?

I'm guessing it has something to do with threads. The game engine spawns 5 threads (+ main is 6 total) which handle things like input and music. Could it be that the main thread is really using 300kb but the other threads combined total 30mb?

Answer (score 2):

`sbrk(0)` only tells you where the end of the data segment is. `malloc()` not only gets memory by extending the data segment, it can also get memory by calling `mmap()` for larger allocations. Also, since you are using several threads, additional arenas for additional threads are probably mmaped, too.

Comment: Is there a way to count all the memory taken up by mmap programmatically?

Comment: @jonr: Read and parse /proc/self/smaps

Comment: Most mallocs have a `mallinfo` function defined in `malloc.h` that lets you query stats about memory usage. You should be careful to use this only after testing (as part of your configure/build scripts) that it exists...